# Functional/integration testing a NodeJS ReST API implementation

Tags: api, node.js, express, integration-testing, mongoose

I've built a NodeJS application using mongoose and express. This application exposes resources in a ReSTful manner, and I'm trying to build a suite of functional/integraiton tests.

This suite, when executed, should fire up my application in an isolated environment (running on localhost is fine), with a custom set of configuration settings (the path to which can be provided as an environment variable). Any other custom setup actions should be performed.

After completing the suite of tests, the (mongodb) database should be dropped, and any custom teardown actions should be performed.

What are some NodeJS frameworks/modules/etc exist to help achieve this goal?

Thanks,
Tharsan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mocha can handle the test framework itself, and Tobi or zombi can do the web calls.

Comment: any examples for use with express?